# Superpowered SDK - Properties of the Low-Pass Filter?

Tags: ios, swift, audio, filter, lowpass-filter

I'm building a mobile app using Superpowered in iOS.

My question:

The cutoff on MOST low-pass filters tends to move quickly between 10,000-20,000khz.

The cutoff also tends to move slowly below 3,000khz.

(Because small changes in frequency are more audible below 10,000khz, and particularly below 3,000khz.)

Is there such a 'ramp' already integrated into the Superpowered SDK low-pass filter?

How do I take advantage of it?

And,

Is it possible to set 'Q' (resonance) and 'Slope' in the filter?

A million thanks,

Bo